# i need help multiplying two strings

Tags: python-3.x

The following error is encountered when running the code below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ladyj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\bv.py", line 5, in <module>
    earnings=str(base_salary*commission_rate)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'


base_salary = input(str('what is your base salary'))
commission_rate = input(str('what is your commission rate'))

earnings=str(base_salary*commission_rate)
print(earnings)
```

Answer (score 0):

input will always return a string, but if you want to do calculations with it, then you will need to convert it to a number. The float() function will do this for you. If the value that was input was not a number you will get a ValueError. If you want to check for this you can use a try/except construct to catch the error.

Here is some working code that uses floats to accomplish what you are trying to do.

```
base_salary = float(input('What is your base salary? '))
commission_rate = float(input('What is your commission rate? '))
earnings = base_salary * commission_rate
print(f'{earnings:.2f}')
```

By the way, I do a lot of work with commission calculations and I'm not sure I would describe commission rate the way you do. Usually we talk about splits, like 60/40 where 60% is base and 40% is commission, in which case the calculation of total earnings would be base/.6, but your interpretation may be different. When I speak of commission rate, it is usually the percentage of total sales that is paid in commission.